# Horizontal recyclerview at the first row and section title in Google Drive

Tags: android, layout

I want to implement the interface like Google Drive in android like my picture below but I don't know how to implement it. I used one recyclerview for horizontal and one recyclerview for vertical but it is not the same to this picture. And I used all both recyclerview in the scrollview and I want to show the section title at the top. It is the same to Google Drive in android.
[image]

Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
<ScrollView>
    <RecyclerView>
          //for horizontal
    </RecyclerView>
    <RecyclerView>
         // for vertical column
    </RecyclerView>

</ScrollView>
```

for horizontal recyclerview

```
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true));
```

for vertical recyclview with 2 column, use GridLayoutManager instead of LinearLayoutManager as below:

```
GridLayoutManager manager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
```

dont forget to put `recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);` for smooth scroll recyclerview inside scrollview

Comment: I already do like this but when I have a lot of data it will show all data in vertical recyclerview without pagination. Any other concept?

Comment: here is the one of the simple pagination recyclerview i used.. https://github.com/MarkoMilos/Paginate

Comment: When I used recyclerview inside the nestedScrollView the recyclerview will not recycle the row item. It will keep all the object of the item after it load the data. So the phone will use a lot of memory and the recyclerview will not smooth when the object not recycle.